# Prototypes and inheritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, var

What is the difference when we declare a object using two different ways as below?

```
var x = {}
```

and

```
var x = function () {}
```

Comment: The second one is called function, which is type of object - it is a callable object

Comment: Difference in what way? The other is an object, the other is a function. There are more differences than similarities.

Comment: But isn't (almost) everything in Javascript is a object? I mean is there difference in regards to inheritance or some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = {}
```

Creates an instance of an object with `Object` as its prototype.

```
var x = function () {}
```

Creates a "constructor function", which when invoked with the keyword `new` returns a new instance of an object with `Object` as its prototype, but with the function as the value of the `constructor` property.

Both can be used for inheritance purposes, `{}` would be used with `Object.create()` and the constructor function with `new`.

```js
var x1 = {prop:"test"};      // Object that inherits from Object
var x2 = Object.create(x1);  // Make new object that inherits from x1
console.log(x2.prop);

// ********************************************************************

// Constructor function that inherits from Object
function y1() {
  // Create instance property
  this.otherProp = "Other value";
}

// Constructor function that will inherit from y1
function y2(){
  // Ensure that the inherited object's constructor gets called
  y1.prototype.constructor.call(this); 
}

// Make y2 inherit from y1
y2.prototype = y1;

// Reset the constructor to correctly make instances
y2.prototype.constructor = new y2();

// Make an instance of the inherited object and test
var inheritedY = new y2();
console.log(inheritedY.otherProp);
```

Creates a "constructor function", which when invoked with the keyword `new` returns a new instance of an object with `Object` as its prototype, but with the function as the value of the `constructor` property.

Both can be used for inheritance purposes, `{}` would be used with `Object.create()` and the constructor function with `new`.

Comment: thanks! So if I'm getting this correct, both `var x` are a child object from Object? And the difference is that first one is only served as an object of Object while the second can be used to create a new object using `new`?

Comment: @ryan9025 No. As I said `{}` is an "instance" of an object that inherited from `Object`, while `function x()` is a function that, when called with `new` will return (in the future) instances of objects that inherit from `Object`.